# How to filter out React Component's props using Typescript?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I use two components: `Test` and `Subtest`. The `Test` component should do some visual decorations and pass portion of it's props down to `Subtest` component. Some of `Subtest` component props are optional and are point out on it's Interface.

`Test` component props interface:

```
interface TestProps {
  prop1: string;
  prop2: string;
  prop3?: string;
  prop4?: string;
}
```

`Test` component:

```
export const Test = (props: TestProps) => {
  const { prop1, prop2: subProp, ...otherSubtestProps } = props;

  const subtestProps: SubtestProps = {
    subProp,
    ...otherSubtestProps
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Test component</p>
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(props).map(prop => (
          <li>
            {prop}: {props[prop]}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <Subtest {...subtestProps} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

`Subtest` component props interface:

```
interface SubtestProps {
  subProp: string;
  prop3?: string;
}
```

`Subtest` component:

```
export const Subtest = (props: SubtestProps) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <hr />
      <p>Subtest component</p>
      <ul>
        {Object.keys(props).map(prop => (
          <li>
            {prop}: {props[prop]}
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
      <hr />
    </div>
  );
};
```

If I call `Subtest` component using `prop4` prop, the compilation will fail with `TS2322` error - the behaviour I expect.
`<Subtest subProp="value 2" prop4="value 4" />`

Nevertheless when I call `Test` component it will pass `prop4` value down to `Subtest` component with no error.
`<Test prop1="value 1" prop2="value 2" prop4="value 4" />` will call `<Subtest subProp="value 2" prop4="value 4" />` with no errors.

The question is, how to make it, that calling `<Test prop1="value 1" prop2="value 2" prop4="value4" />` will call `Subtest` component only with `subProp` and optionally `prop3` props?

`"react": "^16.8.0"`, `"typescript": "^3.3.3"`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To me it looks as though you are just over complicating things and making it look fancy for no real purpose which is then leading you to issues.

I would change you code to the following just for a readability point of view;

```
  const { prop2, prop3 } = props;

  const subtestProps: SubtestProps = {
    subProp: prop2,
    prop3
  };
```

Since this is what you are wanting.

Comment: Seems you're right. I've edited my question with answer based on your opinion.